# How to extract text from Large excel files using TikaOnDotNet library?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, apache-tika

I have few excel files, and I want to extract text from these files using TikaOnDotNet. This library is working file with all the files whose size is less than 160MB, but when I am using larger files, it is showing me this error:

*An unhandled exception of type 'TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.TextExtractionException' occurred in TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction.dll
Additional information: Extraction of text from the file failed*

Below is the code that I am using:

```
var a=new TextExtractor().Extract(filename).Text;
```

Does anyone have a solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- Update the NuGets to the most recent version
- Install NuGets in the same project where you are using Tika methods

I had problem with Tika too: I created methods that used Tika and the NuGets were set into external PCL which I referred in my main project. That caused errors and I still haven't found the solution for it.